# PHP session variable expiration

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Hi Guys I declared a variable session in php wordpress site, but after 5 minutes of no navigation it lost the value, but the session it's still active, and the session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini is set to defaults 1440 seconds (24 minutes). here is my code:

```
public function __construct() { 

    echo '<script>console.log("0: '.session_status().'")</script>'; 

    if ( ( $_SESSION['logged'] != null ) && (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) )
    {

        self::$profile = $_SESSION['logged'];   
        self::$favoriteTeam = self::$profile->favorite_team;

        echo '<script>console.log("1: '.self::$profile->fb_user_id.'")</script>';   
        echo '<script>console.log("2: '.self::$profile->favorite_team.'")</script>';    
        echo '<script>console.log("3: '.self::$favoriteTeam.'")</script>';      

    } 

}


public function(){ $_SESSION['logged'] = self::$profile = $user;    }
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that this is a wordpress project and yes the content it's saved into session variable if i try to debug:

```
echo '<script>console.log("1: '. $_SESSION['logged'].'")</script>';
```

Comment: This would typically be C++ or C#: $_SESSION['logged'] != null. in PHP this would typically be isset($_SESSION['logged'])

Comment: Ok i tried a simple code this way http://www.kanasolution.com/2011/01/session-variable-in-wordpress/ and the session variable persist more than 5 minutes, so I will look for another solution... just save a bool value and load detas from db. THANKS ALL

Answer (score 1):

Have you start the session first before you used that values

```
public function __construct() { 

    session_start();

    echo '<script>console.log("0: '.session_status().'")</script>'; 

    if ( ( $_SESSION['logged'] != null ) && (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) )
    {

        self::$profile = $_SESSION['logged'];   
        self::$favoriteTeam = self::$profile->favorite_team;

        echo '<script>console.log("1: '.self::$profile->fb_user_id.'")</script>';   
        echo '<script>console.log("2: '.self::$profile->favorite_team.'")</script>';    
        echo '<script>console.log("3: '.self::$favoriteTeam.'")</script>';      
    } 
}

public function()
{ 
        $_SESSION['logged'] = self::$profile = $user;    
}
```

Comment: I'll try now, session_start it's declare at top ofindex, should i redeclare as you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the cookie lifetime is set to low. Check [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

Also don't forget `session_start()`.

Try not forcing a set to $user in `()`:

```
if (isset($user) || !isset(self::$profile)) {
  $_SESSION['logged'] = self::$profile = $user;  
}
```

Comment: cookie lifetime it's set to 0. sesion_start it's decalred at top of index, is it enough?

Comment: That should be ok then. Are you sure that it gets stored in the session? Is the `()` function called?

Comment: yes take a look again to main answer I edited with new informations i forgot to mention. thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer if a little code to try to add in the `()` function. Could it be that you reset the profile each time that function is called?